# Regex for 1 or 2 digits, optional non-alphanumeric, 2 known alphas

Tags: c#, regex, grep

I've been bashing my head against the wall trying to do what should be a simple regex - I need to match, eg `12po` where the `12` part could be one or two digits, then an optional non-alphanumeric like a `:.-,_` etc, then the string `po`.

The eventual use is going to be in `C#` but I'd like it to work in regular `grep` on the command line as well. I haven't got access to `C#`, which doesn't help.

Comment: Over the last nine years this question has amassed far more views and upvotes than I ever expected. Where is this pattern used that so many people find it useful?

Comment: @eykanal I am here because I am searching for part of a very specific pattern in another specific pattern. I am as perplexed as you are.

Comment: @eykanal In case you're curious and this is a useful data point, this is the top result for the google search "regex match 1 or 2 digit number", which is a slightly broader question, but may explain why you're getting so many views.

Answer (score 91):

```
^[0-9]{1,2}[:.,-]?po$
```

Add any other allowable non-alphanumeric characters to the middle brackets to allow them to be parsed as well.

Comment: ...but add them before the `-` or you'll get surprising results.

Answer (score 52):

```
^\d{1,2}[\W_]?po$
```

`\d` defines a number and `{1,2}` means 1 or two of the expression before, `\W` defines a non word character.

Comment: \W doesn't include _, which he wanted

Comment: Fantastic - thanks very much. Works in code but grep still gives me 'unmatched ^ or ]', but I can live with that. I took off the '^' and '$' from beginning and end btw, forgot to say that the string can occur anywhere, not just on a single line.

Comment: In that case, use `\b` anchors around your regex.

Answer (score 10):

```
^[0-9][0-9]?[^A-Za-z0-9]?po$
```

You can test it here: http://www.regextester.com/

To use this in C#,

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^[0-9][0-9]?[^A-Za-z0-9]?po$");
if (r.Match(someText).Success) {
   //Do Something
}
```

Remember, @ is a useful symbol that means the parser takes the string literally (eg, you don't need to write \\ for one backslash)